# Error with TArray floats in Unreal Engine C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

C++ and Unreal newbie here. I have a class with a function I'm calling from a Blueprint. I want to create an array of floats (converted from a string) and push a value from Blueprint to it, but I'm getting an error I don't quite understand.

I'm declaring the array like this in my header file:

```
private:
    TArray<float> SensorValues[5];
```

Then I try to push a value from my Blueprint in the cpp file:

```
void Test::UpdateSensor(FString SensorValue)
{
    float sensorVal = FCString::Atof(*SensorValue);
    SensorValues.Push(sensorVal);
}
```

Which results in this error:

```
   error C2228: left of '.Push' must have class/struct/union
```

Any guidance?

Comment: `TArray<float> SensorValues[5];` declares a raw array of 5 `TArray<float>` instances. Raw arrays do not provide any member functions, hence the error message.

Comment: So what should it look like? Originally I had this as the declaration in the header, but it gives the same compiler error:

    TArray<float> SensorValues;

Does that still result in a raw array? If so, why?

Comment: `TArray<float> SensorValues;` doesn't result in a raw array.

Comment: But if I do that, it still results in the same compiler error when I try to push to it.    

error C2228: left of '.Push' must have class/struct/union

Comment: The code appears confused on the type of SensorValues.  Does the TArray<float> type have a method called Push?  If so you need to pick a specific element in the SensorValues array like SensorValues[1].Push(sensorVal);

Comment: Trying to index it like you suggested gives more errors, since it's not a valid element. TArray does have a Push method as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to include the header :D

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation TArray is dynamic array, so you should have tried

`private:
    TArray<float> SensorValues;`

besides

`private:
    TArray<float> SensorValues[5];`